# AWS Powershell Encrypting S3 bucket

Tags: powershell

I need to encrypt AWS S3 bucket using PowerShell. Default encryption should be good. I am going through the following Set-S3BucketEncryption Cmdlet and did not understand how to use the switch -ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration_ServerSideEncryptionRule

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=Set-S3BucketEncryption.html&tocid=Set-S3BucketEncryption

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem trying to get Set-S3BucketEncryption to work initially after reading the docs.  I kept getting the error

> The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against
>   our published schema

I got it working by trial and error, using the following syntax (you'll need to defined the variables $bucketName, $accountId, $keyId, $region)

```
Set-S3BucketEncryption -BucketName $bucketName -ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration_ServerSideEncryptionRule @{ ServerSideEncryptionByDefault=@{ ServerSideEncryptionAlgorithm="aws:kms"; ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceKeyId="arn:aws:kms:$region:$accountId:key/$keyId" } } -Region $region
```

Also, make sure you have a recent version of AWS PowerShell tools installed.  The default encryption functionality was added fairly recently.

Hope this helps